# How to automaticaly dowload library from github inside lib folder cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

I want to create my first big project in c++.
And I need to use some library. So I have made this structure

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── README.md
├── src
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── HelloWorld.cpp
│   ├── HelloWorld.h
│   └── main.cpp
├── tst
|   ├── CMakeLists.txt
|   ├── HelloWorld-test.cpp
|   └── main.cpp
└── lib
```

and I want to automatically download and place the library in the lib folder. In my case, I want to clone googletest int lib folder. So I have tried that in my main project CMakeLists.txt file:

```
if(UNIX)
    file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/lib/googletest)
    execute_process(
            COMMAND git clone "https://github.com/google/googletest.git" googletest
            WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
    add_subdirectory(lib/googletest)
endif(UNIX)
```

But when I build I have this error :

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:17 (add_subdirectory):
  add_subdirectory given source "lib/googletest" which is not an existing
  directory.
```

Comment: GTest documents this using `ExternalProject_Add`: https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/README.md#incorporating-into-an-existing-cmake-project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that the repository is cloned to the binary directory, but `add_subdirectory` looks for the directory relative to the source directory.

You need to use `add_subdirectory` with an absolute path here and pass a build directory. Furthermore add quotes to avoid issues with spaces in the file path.

```
set(REPO_PARENT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/lib")
set(REPO_DIR "${REPO_PARENT}/googletest")
set(REPO_BIN_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/googletest_build")

file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${REPO_DIR})
file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${REPO_BIN_DIR})
execute_process(
        COMMAND git clone "https://github.com/google/googletest.git" googletest
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${REPO_PARENT})

add_subdirectory(${REPO_DIR} ${REPO_BIN_DIR})
```